# How to make jQuery animation look smooth?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm sitting on this animation for a long time and can't think the best way for it to work. I want that first and second li item would slowly fadeOut and at the same time sixth and seventh item would fadeIn while all items are slowly moving to the left.
Here is how my animation looks like, it's nothing like I wanted.. 
https://jsfiddle.net/nqo65mcd/2/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.feedbak-logo li').slice(5).hide();
});

jQuery('.feedbak-logo li').click(function (){
  jQuery('.feedbak-logo li[data-number = "1"]').fadeOut({queue: false, duration: '500'});
  jQuery('.feedbak-logo li[data-number = "2"]').fadeOut({queue: false, duration: '1000'});
  position = 80;
  jQuery('.feedbak-logo li').animate({queue: false,left: '-='+position+'px'}, 1000);
  jQuery('.feedbak-logo li[data-number = "6"]').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: '500'});
  jQuery('.feedbak-logo li[data-number = "7"]').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: '1000'});
});
```

Comment: try playing with opacity instead of fade; the problem with fade is that at the end of it, it's going to have a `display:none` added to it, so any element after it will jump... animating opacity for fading and margins for the move will get you what you want...

Comment: @webeno Now I got it. But now there is another problem I don't know how I should edit my code, it's a bit more complex then I paste here. I need to select first and last visible li. In my case I did that like this `var last = jQuery('.feedbak-logo li:visible:last');`. How should I do that with opacity? Is it only possible with a loop or is there any better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery animations are good enough, people say it's slow etc, but it is the best available out there as far browser compatibility and performance go.
Sure, once installed, greensock is faster, but nobody seems to calculate the extra server request, CSS has cross browsers issues, the jQuery animate method despite all it's reputation of being slow is the best if you run jquery anyway already and for small-medium sized projects.

The relevant parts of the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var items = $('.feedbak-logo li');
 items.slice(5).hide();
 });
 var items = $('.feedbak-logo li');
 items.click(function() {
 items.eq(0).fadeOut(1000);
 items.eq(1).fadeOut(1000);

items.eq(0).animate({
left: 50
}, {
duration: 1000,
step: function(now, fx) {
  items.gt(0).css("left", now);
}
});
items.eq(5).fadeIn(1000);
items.eq(6).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Here is the improved code where everything runs smooth without being jumpy.

```
$('#one').click(function(){
original();
});
$('#two').click(function(){
backToOriginal();
});


function original() {
var items = $('.feedbak-logo li');
items.slice(5).css({'opacity': 0});

items.eq(0).animate({opacity: 0, left:'-30px'},500);
items.eq(1).animate({opacity: 0, left:'-30px'},500);
items.eq(5).animate({opacity: 1},500);
items.eq(6).animate({opacity: 1},500);
items.each(function(i) {
setTimeout(function() {

  items.removeClass("nonAnimated").addClass("animated");
}, 200 * i);


});
}

function backToOriginal() {
var items = $('.feedbak-logo li');


items.eq(0).animate({opacity: 1, left:'30px'},500);
items.eq(1).animate({opacity: 1, left:'30px'},500);
items.eq(5).animate({opacity: 0},500);
items.eq(6).animate({opacity: 0},500);
items.each(function(i) {
setTimeout(function() {
  items.removeClass("animated")
    .addClass
  ("nonAnimated");

}, 100 * i);


});
}
```

The codepen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/grRaEW

I don't know where to start, learn the jquery animate documentation inside out, it is really the least worst of all the bad stuff out there. This becomes clear when the client asks you why the site does not work in half the mobile browsers.

Do not select the elements like that, always always cache the DOM elements references with Jquery, especially with animations.

For a bit a different approach in native JS, try this:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/PzYXmv

No idea if this is useful but this is a very similar native js implementation, i can do exactly what youa re looking for, but tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your code, would it be possible to move element to left while fading?

Comment: Check this, I can change this to what you look for tomorrow  http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/PzYXmv

Comment: could you help me with this animation? I've tried making but can't figure it out how.

Comment: Tell me what you want it to do and I will make a vanilla js and a jq example tmro:-)

Comment: Here's the code I've been working on, everything works except animation. https://jsfiddle.net/nqo65mcd/4/ basically what I want is just a smooth animation when Li items would slide to left or right while fading. If you could give me a smooth animation example, I would do the rest by myself. Also, maybe you have some advices to improve the code?

Comment: Ah ok, you know, if you use fadeIn, the transition to the left will never be smooth, because fadeOut/in set the display property to none. and display properties cannot be animated. No big deal this can be made smooth by playing with the opacity value. I am doing this right now. Be ready in few mins.

Comment: @ Giedidius, check the code in the above link now, ask if anything is unclear, it looks complicated, but it is really simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Anytime, just ask:-)

Answer (score 0):

As said **webeno**, you can try to use `.animate({'width': 'toggle'});` instead of `.fadeout()`

Comment: I appreciate the credit, however this answer is far from complete, so either just vote up my comment, add one to the question, or elaborate...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example of doing it with CSS transitions by combining `opacity` and `transform`:

https://jsfiddle.net/MattDiMu/t3umvbcx/

edit: corrected url

edit2: a votedown, for not providing the code directly? well, here it is...

```
.fade-in,
.action .fade-out{
  opacity: 0;
}
.action .fade-in,
.fade-out {
  opacity: 1;
}

.action li {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}

jQuery('.feedbak-logo').click(function (){
    $(this).addClass('action');
});
```

Comment: @webeno it's added